# Different App Name for each country and for Icon label?

Tags: android

Is it possible to define the App Name different for each language and also to show a different name beneath the app icon in the homescreen than the name displayed in the google play store for example?

Comment: What is an `icon label`?

Comment: Take your Android Device. Go to your Application List. You see Mani Applications with icons and labels/titles/app names. Call them what you want.

Comment: I call them "App name" and "Icon"

Comment: Wrong. Cause i never said anything about different icons. i said differnt icon labels. there is a huge differnt. one is an icon. one is text :D

Comment: Wrong. No such a thing like an "icon label" exists. An icon is a picture. A label is a text.

Comment: And you cant have a text belonging to an icon? xD That is what every icon has in the android home screen ;) I recommend a little more complex way of thinking.

Comment: No. An icon is an icon. A label is a label. OF COURSE you can have a TextView which has drawables inside and also a text. But what is an `icon label` is still a mystery, to me.

Comment: If it is only a mistery for you i have no problem with it. just take a look what google says about icon labels ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create separate folder for each country like values-es, values-de.

Create `strings.xml` for all the folders and give app name difference for each country.

And then try changing device language to different country language, You will see that app name will change according to the different `strings.xml` file.

And for app icon also you can create different drawable folder for each country.

Comment: ok. what about different name in homescreen beneath the icon?

Comment: so i cant have different home icon label than app name?